# How to make row go all the way to the bottom of the page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am using bootstrap grid for my wbe app. I am wondering how can I make a row go all the way to the bottom of the page - in case there is no additional content. In other case, where there is some content, I would like a div to stretch as much as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You just need to give height: 100%; to the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extend the div to full height. You need to add `height: 100%` to all the wrappers containing the div including the div itself. Here is the code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="full">

  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS required.

```
html, body, .row {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.full {
  background: pink;
  height:100%;
}
```

If there is a `container` class wrapping the `row` then that has to be included as well along with the others.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnauaeq8/) or [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrgbeL). whatever you like :-)